# Problem displaying meaningful error message from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm calling a Razor Pages handler from AJAX like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '?handler=Delete',
    data: {
        id: $(this).data('id')
    }
})
.fail(function (e) {
    alert(e.responseText);
});
```

And here's my handler that tests what happens if an exception occurs:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnGetDelete(int id)
{
    throw new Exception("This is an exception.");
}
```

If an exception is thrown in my handler, then I want to display a description of the error. The problem is that `e.responseText` contains *way* more information than I want to display to the user. It includes a description of the exception, along with the stack trace, headers and a lot of other stuff.

In the example above, I'd want to only display "This is an exception.". Is my only solution to try and parse the message from `e.responseText`? Is this what other people are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the example above, I'd want to only display "This is an exception.".

To display "This is an exception.", you can use following code snippet:

```
.fail(function (e) {
    //console.log(e);
    var mes = e.responseText.split('\n')[0];
    alert(mes.substring(17, mes.length - 1));
})
```

Test Result:

[image]

**Update:**

If possible, you can try to dynamically capture exception occurs in that specific handler method, then generate your expected response, like below.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    try
    {
        await next();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("{request_path_here}") && context.Request.Query["handler"].Any())
        {
            if (context.Request.Query["handler"]== "Delete")
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                var result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { error = ex.Message });
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The `responseText` would be `"{"error":"This is an exception."}"`, and you can get exception message using `JSON.parse(e.responseText).error`.

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my specialty is parsing text. Your code is hard coding assumptions about the error text and I'm not good with that. Anyway, my question was if I have to parse it or if this information is available in a more predictable way.

Comment: Hi @JonathanWood, please check my updates. Hoping this workaround can help achieve your requirement.

Comment: What is `app.Use()`?

Comment: It could help add a middleware delegate defined in-line to the application's request pipeline. You can get more information from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).